# Can not return value after a httpClient.GetAsync in ASP.NET Core 7 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 7 Web API.

In on API method, I use `HttpClientFactory` to grab something, but after that, I can not return values.

It only returns 200 OK

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto user)
{
    return OK(new { Code = 0});   // can return 

    await httpClient.GetAsync(...
    return Ok(new { Code = - 1 });    // can not return;
}
```

Comment: [For a method with a return type, only one `return` keyword can be used, and the following code will not be executed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK6g8.png)